# Does it omit the single quote(')?

Tags: grammar, gerunds

> [While this had previously been put down to participants mis-seeing the
> shape, Otten and colleagues had doubts.](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2023/apr/05/short-term-memory-illusions-study)

Should it be "While this had previously been put down to participant***s'*** mis-seeing the shape, Otten and colleagues had doubts." ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That symbol is called an "apostrophe"  It looks identical to a closing single quote, it doesn't end a quote.

Gerunds do sometimes have a subject with an "'s" or in possessive, but that isn't needed here.  The words "participants" is both the object of the preposition "to" and the implied subject of the gerund.  It doesn't require a "'s" as an object.  If it was given one, it wouldn't be wrong, and the meaning would be the same.

You could see this more clearly if a pronoun had been used:

> ... was put down to me mis-seeing the shape

> ... was put down to my mis-seeing the shape

I would accept either of these as correct.

> *... was put down to I mis-seeing the shape

But this is certainly wrong.